# Search for element in XML file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an XML file structured like this:

```
<movies>
    <movie>
        <title>A title</title>
        <year>2016</year>
    <boxoffice>18 million</boxoffice>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>Second title</title>
        <year>2010</year>
        <boxoffice>10 million</boxoffice>
    </movie>
<movies>
```

I want to find all movies after year 2015 and show it in a table using jquery. 
I get the xml using:

```
function getx() {
            var x = $.ajax({
                url:      movies.xml,
                datatype: "xml",
                async:    false
            });
            return x.responseXML;
        }
```

and go though it using:

```
function find(year){
            var x = getx();
            $(x).find("year").each(function() {
                if (Number($(this).text()) > Number(year) {
                    $(document.getElementById("results")).append("<tr><td>" + $(this).text() + "</td></tr>");
                }
            });
        }
```

This returns creates a table row containing 2016. How could I modify this to search for one element and once found return all elements from the collection it belongs to? (I want to get a table row with title, year and boxoffice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: using an ajax call as sync is an issue, I suggest you to use a [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success).

Second:  in order to convert an xml to a jQuery object you can use [jQuery.parseXML( data )](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/). After the conversion you can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for selecting the elements you need and append them to the table.

In jquery [the ID Selector (“#id”)](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) is:

```
$('#results')
```

instead of:

```
$(document.getElementById("results"))
```

In order to get the siblings elements you can use: [Node.nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) and [Node.previousSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) or you can use the [jQuery.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [jQuery.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

The snippet:

```js
var xml = '<movies>\
        <movie>\
        <title>A title</title>\
<year>2016</year>\
<boxoffice>18 million</boxoffice>\
</movie>\
<movie>\
<title>Second title</title>\
<year>2010</year>\
<boxoffice>10 million</boxoffice>\
</movie>\
</movies>';

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
var jqXml = $(xmlDoc).find('year').filter((idx, ele) => {return +ele.textContent > 2015;});
jqXml.each(function(idx, ele) {
    $('#results').append("<tr><td>" + ele.previousSibling.textContent +
                    "</td><td>" + ele.textContent + "</td><td>" + 
                    ele.nextSibling.textContent + "</td></tr>");
})
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="results">
    
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input on this. However the result returns "<td>2016</td>" which is what I achieved with my code as well. What I want to get is: "<td>A Title</td><td>2016</td><td>18 million</td>

Comment: @PaulB Sorry for the delay. Answer updated. Let me know.

Comment: yep seems to be working. Though I changed some of the code to fit better my project you did set me on the right direction. Thanks.